# Passing template instance data as a keyword argument to a nested template

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a template, called `skillbar`, which takes two keyword arguments, `title` and `value`.

So, for example, I could type:

```
  {{>skillbar title="strength"  value=51}}
```

To render a skillbar with the label "strength" that has its progress bar filled up 51%.

---

I have a bunch of these skillbars I would like to create and rather than doing something like:

```
{{>skillbar title="strength"     value=51}}
{{>skillbar title="willpower"    value=80}}
{{>skillbar title="imagination"  value=30}}
```

Id rather create a separate template, which I can register a helper on that contains an array of objects that I can use as parameters.

```
Template.abilities.helpers({
  abilities: [
    {title: 'strength',    value: 51},
    {title: 'willpower',   value: 80},
    {title: 'imagination', value: 30} 
  ]
});
```

Presumably then, I could `{{#each}}` over the `abilities` array in my markup can create the `skillbar` template instances that way.

This encapsulates the essence of what I want to do, but it throws a syntax error:

```
<template name="abilities">
  {{#each abilities}}
    {{>skillbar title={{title}} value={{value}} }}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax instead :

```
<template name="abilities">
  {{#each abilities}}
    {{> skillbar}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

When invoking a child template, if you don't pass any argument its current data context will be set to the parent one, which happens to be the currently iterated over ability from the `{{#each}}` loop.

Alternatively you could use this syntax :

```
<template name="abilities">
  {{#each abilities}}
    {{> skillbar title=title value=value}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

But in this specific case it would be redundant, but could be useful to rename parameters for whatever reason.

Comment: I will accept this once SO lets me. Excellent answer. Could you point me to some docs that outline this behavior?